# Como convertir una instancia de una clase en un byte[] c#

Tags: c#

Quiero convertir una instancia de una clase en un byte[] . La finalidad de esto es enviarlo por un servicio rest. Si existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo me lo pueden comentar. El objeto que quiero enviar es un objeto dinámico del cual no conozco las propiedades ni nada y el contenido puede variar.

```
     Grid contenido = Miscelanea.Miscelanea.establecerContent(respuesta);


        object data = (object)contenido;

        var x = Convert.FromBase64String(data.ToString());
```

Lo anterior da error. Como puedo convertir el objeto contenido en un byte[] o como puedo enviarlo por una rest. Lo que pasa es que al momento de serializarlo me da un error que dice que el objeto esta marcado como no serializable!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerte uso de la clase [BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8).

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de uso, tanto para Serializar como Deserializar.

```
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Coche c = new Coche
        {
            Color = "Rojo",
            Puertas = 3
        };

        byte[] byteArray = ObjToByteArray((object)c);
        object o = ByteArrayToObj(byteArray);

        Coche desCoche = (Coche)o;
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static byte[] ObjToByteArray(object o)
    {
        if (o == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, o);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static object ByteArrayToObj(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        if (byteArray == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {
            return (object)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
```

En caso de que quieras aplicarlo a una clase como en mi ejemplo, hay que tener en cuenta que ésta debe tener el atributo [Serializable]

```
[Serializable]
public class Coche
{
    private string _color;
    private int _puertas;

    public string Color { get => _color; set => _color = value; }
    public int Puertas { get => _puertas; set => _puertas = value; }

    public Coche()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Usa **Newtonsoft.Json** para convertir el objeto a un JSON y luego obtener un array de bytes de ese JSON

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contenido));
```

Answer (score -2):

Si necesitas enviarlo por un rest, podrias enviarlo como un json, usando la libreria **Newtonsoft.Json**

```
Grid contenido = Miscelanea.Miscelanea.establecerContent(respuesta);

object data = (object)contenido;

//En la variable _data, tendras el json de lo que sea k tenga el data

string _data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)
```